# Using a structured query to fetch values based on key in array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore I have a document structured as shown below.

I am trying to set up a Zapier Zap that will allow me to fetch the store name, based on the storeId. It requires a JSON structured query that fetches the data.

Is it possible to do, and where should I begin, I find the documentation lacking examples. The only query I have right now is as shown below, but obviously, it does not work since all data is in a single document.

```
"where": {
    "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
            "fieldPath": "stores/*/storeId"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
            "stringValue": "def"
        }
    }
}
```

Document structure

```
{ 
  "stores": {
   "0": {
      "storeId": "abc",
      "name": "Store 1"
   },
   "1": {
      "storeId": "def",
      "name": "Store 2"
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with an array field, but you can if you change that array to a map field. Something like this:

```
mycollection/mydoc

{
  "someotherfield": "foo",
  "stores": {
     "abc": {
       "name": "Store 1"
      },
     "def": {
       "name": "Store 2"
      }
 }
}
```

Now you can use a field mask:

```
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY-PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/mycollection/mydoc?mask.fieldPaths=stores.abc.name
```

Response:

```
{
 "name": "projects/MY-PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/mycollection/mydoc",
 "fields": {
  "stores": {
   "mapValue": {
    "fields": {
     "abc": {
      "mapValue": {
       "fields": {
        "name": {
         "stringValue": "Store 1"
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 },
 "createTime": "2019-04-20T19:14:01.792855Z",
 "updateTime": "2019-04-22T18:07:05.660561Z"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that stores is not the collection, it is inside the document. I only have one document in the collection not multiple

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for clarifying. So `stores` is a field within some document that contains an array of map values. Generally, Cloud Firestore is geared towards returning whole documents. Would it work for you to make a `stores` collection?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm locked on the structure so changing it to a collection is not an option. Except maybe I could make some kind of function that created a new collection from that document. But it seems excessive to me to do that

Comment: You can use a field-mask if you change that array to a map. Updated my answer. Also, if you store a lot of data in a single doc, watch out for the 1 MiB doc size limit.